# Windows Server 2012 - start up using Runas Administrator

Tags: batch-file, startup, windows-server-2012

I need to start an application by running "Run as Administrator". I have been searching for the command line and tool, it seems psexec.exe able to provide this functionality.

However, I have no success running it.

psexec -u myowndomain\david123 -p myPassword1 "E:\Temp\StartUp.exe"

I do not need to run remote computer. I just want to simulate the "Run as Administrator" when I do it manually.

Is the command correct ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a runas command, you can read more there: [RUNAS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525(v=ws.11).aspx)

runas [{/profile | /noprofile}] [/env] [{/netonly | /savecred}] [/smartcard] [/showtrustlevels] [/trustlevel] /user: " "